# Paypal Button Not Working - We are sorry error

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am trying to integrate PayPal to my website. My requirement is that I want to pass a computer generated amount to PayPal to make payment of that amount.
But when I make payment using button , I am taken to website for payment, Where I login using sandbox account and make payment. But when I make payment I get a message saying

> We’re sorry Things don’t appear to be working at the moment.

[image]
I searched about the possible problem's from similar questions asked and implemented the suggested fix's which is Hosting a button in a server and providing different parameters , But no luck. Here's the code I am using

```
    <form 
                action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="**********@gmail.com">
                <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Product1">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00">
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
                <!--in custom field add user id-->
                      <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="102">
                <!-- Specify URLs -->
                <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://www.shreyash.tech'>
                <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://www.google.co.in'>
                <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
                <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
    </form>
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: have you created a sandbox account?

Answer (score 0):

It looks the issue with your sandbox account. Would you please create your new sandbox seller and buyer test accounts and try again.
Here is the [link](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1408&expand=true&locale=en_US) for your reference to create PayPal sandbox account.

Comment: no my sandbox account is working with other integrations. I suppose its not the problem